# Finding closest sum of numbers to a given number

Tags: javascript, php

Say I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
and I would like to find the closest sum of numbers to a given number. Sorry for the crappy explanation but here's an example:

Say I have a list [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] I want to find the closest numbers to, say, 10.

Then the method should return 6 and 4 or 7 and 3 because its the closest he can get to 10. So 5 + 4 would be wrong because thats 9 and he can make a 10.

another example : you want the closest to 14 , so then he should return 7 and 6

If you got any questions plz ask because its difficult to explain what I want :P

Comment: How many times can you use any item from the array? For example: if the given number is 10, then you can get a sum of ten times 1 to get to 10. Also:  this looks like a school question.

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: would `2+3+5` be allowed?

Comment: @peter Can you add some more details to your question? Its quite confusing.

Comment: what if the input number is 28 ?

Comment: Are you looking for an answer in PHP or Javascript? The obvious solution has an order O(N!) - is this an issue?

Comment: @messerbill Yes that would be allowed, as much numbers as needed

Comment: @Manwal I tried all the answers but i wasnt clear about what i wanted so still no answer

Comment: @klaar if the list is like this  [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,7]  you can use 6 twice

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest than it should be 7+6+5+4+3+2+1

Comment: @symcbean uhm I dont mind if its php or javascript, but its for my site so I want it to be as efficient as possible :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions for `combine`, `locationOf`, are taken from different answers, written by different authors.

```js
printClosest([0.5,2,4] , 5);
printClosest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 28);
printClosest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10.9);
printClosest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10, 2);
printClosest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10, 3);
printClosest([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 14, 2);

function printClosest(array, value, limit) {
  var checkLength = function(array) {
    return array.length === limit;
  };
  var combinations = combine(array); //get all combinations
  combinations = limit ? combinations.filter(checkLength) : combinations;//limit length if required
  var sum = combinations.map(function(c) { //create an array with sum of combinations
    return c.reduce(function(p, c) {
      return p + c;
    }, 0)
  });
  var sumSorted = sum.slice(0).sort(function(a, b) {//sort sum array
    return a - b;
  });

  index = locationOf(value, sumSorted);//find where the value fits in
  //index = (Math.abs(value - sum[index]) <= Math.abs(value - sum[index + 1])) ? index : index + 1;
  index = index >= sum.length ? sum.length - 1 : index;
  index = sum.indexOf(sumSorted[index]);//get the respective combination

  console.log(sum, combinations, index);

  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML += "value : " + value + " combi: " + combinations[index].toString() + " (limit : " + (limit || "none") + ")<br>";
}


function combine(a) {
  var fn = function(n, src, got, all) {
    if (n == 0) {
      if (got.length > 0) {
        all[all.length] = got;
      }
      return;
    }
    for (var j = 0; j < src.length; j++) {
      fn(n - 1, src.slice(j + 1), got.concat([src[j]]), all);
    }
    return;
  }
  var all = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    fn(i, a, [], all);
  }
  all.push(a);
  return all;
}

function locationOf(element, array, start, end) {
  start = start || 0;
  end = end || array.length;
  var pivot = parseInt(start + (end - start) / 2, 10);
  if (end - start <= 1 || array[pivot] === element) return pivot;
  if (array[pivot] < element) {
    return locationOf(element, array, pivot, end);
  } else {
    return locationOf(element, array, start, pivot);
  }
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"><pre>
```

Comment: Yeah really nice, this is what i was looking for, could you make it such that if im looking for closest to 5 the sum of numbers cant be greater than 5? Like this : [0.5,2,4] the closest would be 4+2 but the sum cant be greater than 5 so he would take 2 + 0.5

Comment: Yes, its possible, I just commented out one line for that. See that `10.9` gives `3,7` if you uncomment that line it will give `4,7` as `11` is more *close* to `10.9`. Please feel free to change things around as per your requirements :)

Comment: The algorithm took `4,0.5` not `2,0.5` :)

Comment: Oh yeah that was a mistake by myself i meant 4 + 0.5 ofcourse xD

Answer (score 1):

```
 var data= [1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7];
  var closest = 14;
 for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
    for (var y = x+1; y < data.length; y++) {
             if(data[x] + data[y] == closet){
                     alert(data[x].toString() + "  " + data[y].toString());
                }
            }
       }
```

Comment: OP said _I would like to find the closest sum of numbers_. You are only alerting exact sums here.

Comment: Yep i would like to find the closes sum of numbers, still thx for helping :)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understood from your question, I made this snippet. I assumed you did not wanted to have the same digit twice (e.g 14 => 7 + 7).

It is working with your examples.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];

var a = 0, b = 0;
var nb = 14;

for(var i in arr) {
  for(var j in arr) {
    if(i != j) {
      var tmp = arr[i] + arr[j];
      if(tmp <= nb && tmp > a + b) {
        a = arr[i];
        b = arr[j];
      }
    }
  }
}

document.write("Closest to " + nb + " => " + a + " + " + b);
```

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear but I want it to work with multiple numbers, for example if you have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and you would have the closest to 19 then instead of 6 + 7 the answer should be 7 + 6 + 5 + 1 , Thanks for helping me out  tho appreciate it :) Also the same diggit twice is allowed :)

Comment: This only finds one possible answer. It can't deal with the case where a value appears more than once in the input set. It finds a solution within bounds rather than nearest to the target.

Comment: @Peter Same digit twice is allowed only if it appears twice in the array right? From your question I assumed you only wanted two terms sum so... I misunderstood that :/

Comment: @PierreC.Yeah thats right, yeah sorry my question was really confusing sorry about that, thanks for your time to help me out tho :)

Answer (score 1):

I have a little bit long winded solution to the problem just so it is easier to see what is done.

The main benefits with solution below:

- The second loop will not start from beginning of the array again. What I mean that instead of having loop_boundary for second loop as 0 as you normally would, here it starts from next index. This helps if your numbers array is long. However, if it as short as in example, the impact in performance is minimal. Decreasing first loop's boundary by one will prevent errors from happening.
- Works even when the wanted number is 1 or negative numbers.

Fiddle:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u3v4yp9g/)

The code:

```
var numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var wanted_number = 1;
var closest_range, closest1, closest2 = null;

var loop1_boundary = numbers.length-1;
for(var i=0; i<loop1_boundary; i++) {

    var start_index = i+1;
    var loop2_boundary = numbers.length;

    for(var k=start_index; k<loop2_boundary; k++) {

        var number1 = parseInt(numbers[i]);
        var number2 = parseInt(numbers[k]);

        var sum = number1 + number2;
        var range = wanted_number - sum;

        document.write( number1+' + '+number2 +' < '+closest_range+'<br/>' );

        if(Math.abs(range) < Math.abs(closest_range) || closest_range == null ) {
            closest_range = range;
            closest1 = number1;
            closest2 = number2;
        }

    }

    if(range==0){
        break;
    }
}

document.write( 'closest to given number was '+closest1+' and '+closest2+'. The range from wanted number is '+closest_range );
```

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear but I want it to work with multiple numbers, for example if you have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and you would have the closest to 19 then instead of 6 + 7 the answer should be 7 + 6 + 5 + 1 , Thanks for helping me out  tho appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

This proposal generates **all possible combinations**, collects them in an object which takes the sum as key and filters then the closest sum to the given value.

```js
function getSum(array, sum) {
    function add(a, b) { return a + b; }

    function c(left, right) {
        var s = right.reduce(add, 0);
        if (s > sum) {
            return;
        }
        if (!result.length || s === result[0].reduce(add, 0)) {
            result.push(right);
        } else if (s > result[0].reduce(add, 0)) {
            result = [right];
        }
        left.forEach(function (a, i) {
            var x = left.slice();
            x.splice(i);
            c(left.slice(0, i), [a].concat(right));
        });
    }

    var result = [];
    c(array, [], 0);
    return result;
}

function print(o) {
    document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(o, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
}

print(getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 10));
print(getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 14));
print(getSum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], 19));
```

Comment: Sorry I was a bit unclear but I want it to work with multiple numbers, for example if you have [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] and you would have the closest to 19 then instead of 6 + 7 the answer should be 7 + 6 + 5 + 1 , Thanks for helping me out  tho appreciate it :)